# More than one library class in a taglib.xml

Tags: xml, jsf, facelets, taglib

Is there a way that i can use more (custom) library at taglib.functions.xml, something like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE facelet-taglib PUBLIC
        "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Facelet Taglib 1.0//EN"
        "facelet-taglib_1_0.dtd">
<facelet-taglib>
    <!-- <namespace>http://loxon.hu/jsf/fw/functions</namespace>-->
    <library-class>com.loxon.fw.common.web.util.JsfCommonLibrary</library-class>
    <library-class>com.loxon.fw.rt.web.util.JsfCommonLibrary</library-class>
</facelet-taglib>
```

Unfortunately this is not a correct syntax, i can not use more of one `<library-class/>` in a `<facelet-taglib/>`...

Or should i use a new taglib.xml??? everytime when i need a new library?

Some idea appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One `*taglib.xml` per library is the correct choice.